# Can I translate the viewport in css?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to pan around boxes that exists in a 2d plane. Each box has coordinates translated, x and y. Sometimes the boxes are outside of my view:

Say I have a box that's currently out of my view:

```
<div class='box'></div>

.box {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;    
    transform:translate(-5000px,0px); 
 }
```

I don't want to change the coordinates of the boxes. I'd like to change the coordinates of the viewport so I can see this box. Is this possible? Note I'd like to be able animate the viewport to the new coordinates.

Comment: Can I ask why it is necessary to move the viewport around rather than the boxes themselves?

Comment: For performance reasons. Think scrolling/panning/etc.

Comment: Perhaps a better question might be: How do you move around your elements with out causing performance issues? If using transforms is (for some reason, even with the various hacks) still causing issues, what about playing with positioning? Surely moving boxes around isn't giving you grief? The information you have provided leaves me to believe that you are not providing the whole picture. You could even put all your elements in one big parent container and just move that guy around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what do you mean?

Just translate the viewport...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.querySelector('#viewport-content').style.transform = 'translate(-200px, -200px)'; 
});
```

```css
#viewport
{
    height: 200px; 
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#viewport-content
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

#box
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    transform: translate(200px, 200px);
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
    <div id="viewport-content">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Let Me View My Box</button>
```

Comment: If this is indeed what OP is looking for, I think there's some confusion as to what a viewport is.

Comment: I was initially talking about the browser viewport, but this is a brilliant solution as well. i'll see how others respond before marking this. thanks.

Comment: I renamed the elements to improved readbility... This can be adapted to work in the browser viewport, you can use the `body` as `#viewport`